# How to build .app build in qtcreator for MAC

Tags: c++, macos, qt-creator, qt5

I have a C++ Qt Application 
I am using Qt Creator to build it on MAC.
It is making a unix executable file for the same.

Need to know how can I make MyApp.app file using QtCreator?

Answer (score 2):

You configure the type of output in the .pro config file. In the case of an app bundle, you'd add: -

> TEMPLATE = app